# Вопрос по Input, как передвигать текст

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой вопрос, как сделать так чтобы текст когда пишут начал писаться чуть справа а не сразу за `border`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте внутренний отступ слева - input { padding-left: 10px; }